# extraer value de radiobutton dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

buenas tengo este radiobutton dentro de un foreach

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="registro" id="<?php echo $cartelera['id'];  ?>" value="<?php echo $cartelera['id'];  ?>" required>
```

donde su ID y VALUE es dinámico desde la base de datos, son varios radiosbuttons los recorro con un foreach

adjunto imagen de los inputs

[image: o]

quiero extraer su VALUE del radio seleccionado en una variable, y si se decide cambiar de radiobutton.... pues el valor de la variable cambie

quiero extraer el VALUE ya que es el ID de la cartelera y al tener el ID de la cartelera puedo hacer otro llamado a la base de datos para traer la sala correspondiente de dicho input para hacer la reservacion de la butacas

soy nuevo en esto, he estado intentando... y nada, necesito ayuda

Comment: Lo puedes hacer escuchando los eventos on change qué podrías asignar por tipo de elemento (si tienen que ser escuchados todos los radio) o mediante una clase si tiene que ser escuchado un grupo de ellos.

Comment: Quieres extraer el valor del radio tras darle al botón de 'enviar' o cada vez que se seleccione uno distinto?

Comment: cada vez que se seleccione uno distinto sin enviar a otro formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los `radio` que tienen el mismo `name` pueden ser seleccionados uno a la vez. Entonces puedes escuchar el evento `change` para recuperar el `value` del `radio` que haya sido seleccionado.

### Usando jQuery

```js
/* div de prueba */
$divTest = $('#test');
$('input[type=radio][name=registro]').change(function() {

  var mValue = this.value;
  console.log(mValue);
  $divTest.text(`Seleccionaste: ${mValue}`);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Seleccione opción:</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="registro" value="1">
  <label for="one">Uno</label>
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="registro" value="2">
  <label for="two">Dos</label>
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="registro" value="3">
  <label for="three">Tres</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="test"></div>
```

### Usando Javascript puro

```js
/* div de prueba */
var divTest = document.getElementById('test');
/* valor que se recuperará */
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=registro]').forEach(oneRadio => {
  oneRadio.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var mValue = e.target.value;
    console.log(mValue);
    divTest.textContent = `Has seleccionado el valor:  ${mValue}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Seleccione opción:</p>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="one" name="registro" value="1">
  <label for="one">Uno</label>
  <input type="radio" id="two" name="registro" value="2">
  <label for="two">Dos</label>
  <input type="radio" id="three" name="registro" value="3">
  <label for="three">Tres</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="test"></div>
```

Los eventos de escucha se pueden implementar también por clases, o por otros grupos de elementos.