# guardar en una variable y mostrar en consola

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

tengo este codigo para mostrar en consola que input estoy seleccionando..

```
$('input[type=radio][name=registro]').change(function() {
 
    if (this.value == '1') {
        console.log('1');
    }
    else if (this.value == '2') {
        console.log('2');
    }
}
```

como hago para guardarlo en una variable y al mismo tiempo en consola como lo tengo actualmente???

Comment: en un input `hidden` $('input[name=input_hidden]').val(this.value);

Comment: no entiendo....

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente con el valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al margen de que te falta un `)` para cerrar función `change`, podrias asignar el valor a una variable desde el inicio y asi sabrias su valor, algo asi:

```js
$('input[type=radio][name=registro]').change(function() {

  var valor = this.value;

    if (valor == '1') {
        console.log(valor);
        alert(valor);
    }
    else if (valor == '2') {
        console.log(valor);
        alert(valor);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="registro" value="1"><label>1</label>
<input type="radio" name="registro" value="2"><label>2</label>
```

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tienen los `if`? Si se quiere guardar el valor del elemento simplemente se recuperan en el listener, no veo para que sirven los if.

Comment: @A.Cedano si toda la razón, asumo que según el valor, el OP va a hacer algo ademas de solo mostrar en consola. Te soy sincero esa parte la tome de lo publicado por el OP sin fijarme en la utilidad o no de los `IF`.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380273/extraer-value-de-radiobutton-dentro-de-un-foreach

Comment: esta es la pregunta verdadera y con los if lo que hago que los extraigo manuelmente aunque me tarde...